# Problema com editar dados do banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Já tinha feito uma pergunta antes de o porque que os modal não se multiplicavam com o `while` (Já está resolvido). Esse foi o resultado:

```
$editar = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT a.n_processo,a.nome,a.data_nasc,a.cc,g.designacao,
a.ciclo_formacao,t.texto
FROM alunos a, cursos g, tipo_curso t
WHERE a.n_curso = g.n_curso
AND g.id_tipo_curso = t.id_tipo_curso");
?>
<!-- ----------------CABEÇALHO---------------------------- -->

<table class="tabela1">
    <tr>
        <td id="tb1">Nº Processo</font>
        <td id="tb2">Nome</font>
</table>

<?
//---------------DADOS------------------------
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

    echo "<TABLE class='tabela2'>";
    echo "<TR class='tabela2'>";
    echo "<TD  style='padding-left:5px;width:20%;'>".$row['n_processo']."</TD>";
    echo "<TD style='padding-left:15px;width:55%;'>".$row['nome']."</TD>";
    echo "<TD style='text-align: right; letter-spacing: 5px; padding-right:10px;'>";


//  ----------------------------BOTAO EDITAR ------------------------------------ -->

echo "<button class='menubotao' id='editar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal3".$editar."'>
    <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
</button>";

echo "</TR>";

echo "</TABLE>";
echo "<button class='menubotao' id='editar' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal3".$editar."'>
  <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
</button>";

echo"<div id='myModal3".$editar."' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>

<div class='modal-content' style='letter-spacing:0px; text-align:left;'>
<div class='modal-header' style=' background-color:#ff6600;'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
<h4 class='modal-title' style='font-size:25px; color:#FFF;'>Atualizar Dados</h4>
</div>

<div class='modal-body' style='font-size:20px;'>

   <p><b>Nº de processo:</b>
        <input type='text' name='procedit' id='procedit' style='border:0px solid #b3b3b3; width:100px; text-align:center; border-radius:5px; background-color:#bfbfbf;' maxlength'5' id='n_processo' value='".$row['n_processo']."' >
   </p>

<br>

<p><b>Nome:</b> <input type='text' name='nomeedit' id='nomeedit' onkeypress='return letras()' id='nome' required maxlength='150' style='border:0px solid #b3b3b3;background-color:#bfbfbf; width:400px; padding-left:10px; border-radius:5px;' value='".$row['nome']."' ></p>

 <br>

 <p><b>Data Nascimento:</b> <input type='text' id='data_nascedit' maxlength='10' name='data_nasc' style='border:0px solid #b3b3b3; width:130px; background-color:#bfbfbf;text-align:center; border-radius:5px;' value='".$row['data_nasc']."'></p>

 <br>

 <p><b>C.C. <small>(Cãrtao de Cidadão)</small></b>: <input type='text' name='ccedit' style='border:0px solid #b3b3b3; width:160px; text-align:center; border-radius:5px; text-transform:uppercase;background-color:#bfbfbf;' value='".$row['cc']."' id='ccedit'></p>

 <br>

</div>

<div class='modal-footer'>
     <button type='button' id='btnedit' class='btn btn-primary' style='background-color:#ff6600;border:1px solid #ff6600;'><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2x'></i></button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-times fa-2x'></i></button>

 </div>
```

";.....

Tenho também as máscaras para os campos:

```
$("#procedit").mask("99999",{placeholder:""})
$("#ccedit").mask("99999999?9-9aa9", {placeholder: ""});
$("#data_nascedit").mask("99-99-9999",{placeholder:""});
```

O meu problema é que depois da `query` feita, mostra numa tabela os dados em que cada linha de registos dispõe um icon, esse icon serve para aparecer o modal apresentado em cima, com as informações em `inputs` editáveis. E o meu problema é que só na primeira linha da tabela quando clico no icon, os inputs obedecem às mascaras respetivas, já nos outros, não acontece o mesmo. Pensei que talvez precisasse de um contador para o id dos inputs para a máscara, mas não sei como aplicà-lo no javascript, do tipo:

```
contador =0;
contador++;
```

depois nos `input`:

id='....'".$contador"'';

e na máscara:

```
$("#proc"+$contador)....
```

E na página de atualizar os dados tenho:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE alunos SET n_processo = $n_proc, nome = '$nome', data_nasc = '$data_nasc', cc = '$cc' WHERE n_processo = $n_proc"); 

if(!$sql)
{
    echo mysql_error();
    //echo "<script> sweetAlert('Oops...', 'Não foi conseguido atualizar os dados!', 'error'); </script>";
    }else{
        echo"<script> sweetAlert('Sucesso!', 'Dados atualizados com sucesso!', 'success');</script>"; 

}
```

Outro problema que tenho é quando manda para outra página com as informações via `AJAX` para editar na base de dados, só consigo editar apenas o nome, e mesmo assim às vezes não funciona.

```
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE alunos SET n_processo = $n_proc, nome = '$nome', data_nasc = '$data_nasc', cc = '$cc' WHERE n_processo = $n_proc"); 

    if(!$sql)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
        //echo "<script> sweetAlert('Oops...', 'Não foi conseguido atualizar os dados!', 'error'); </script>";
        }else{
        include('menu.php');
        echo"<script> sweetAlert('Sucesso!', 'Dados atualizados com sucesso!', 'success');</script>"; 

    }
```

Isto está um bocado confuso, mas basicamente os modals não partilham a mesma máscara, e o problema do editar provavelmente deve-se a isso? Se alguém souber de algum método para conseguir o pretendido agradecia. Alguma dúvida disponham. Obrigado desde já.

AJAX

```
    function darupdate(editas){

var proc=$(".procedit"+editas).val();
var nome=$(".nomeedit"+editas).val();   
var cc=$(".ccedit"+editas).val();
var data_nasc=$(".data_nascedit"+editas).val();


    $.post('actualiza.php',{ proc: proc, nome: nome, data_nasc: data_nasc, cc: cc },
        function(data)
        {
                $("body").html(data);
        })       

};
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso aqui: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html, Não é a solução do seu problema, porem, é uma forma de melhorar esse código. Mas precisamente, esse trecho '<?php while(conditions) : ?>
... HTML CODE ...
<?php endwhile; ?>'. (Como escrever um bloco HTML dentro de um wilhe, sem usar um echo para cada linha)

Comment: Outra coisa que também pode ser muito útil para você: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php.

Answer (score 1):

> E o meu problema é que só na primeira linha da tabela quando clico no
>   icon, os inputs obedecem às mascaras respetivas, já nos outros, não
>   acontece o mesmo.

```
        $("#procedit").mask("99999",{placeholder:""})
        $("#ccedit").mask("99999999?9-9aa9", {placeholder: ""});
        $("#data_nascedit").mask("99-99-9999",{placeholder:""});
```

O ID é único, se você definir vários campos com o mesmo ID, a query $(#...) vai buscar o primeiro elemento setado com aquele ID.

Solução: Trocar o ID do input por uma classe (Exemplificando em um input, você deve replicar a solução para os outros).

```
    <p><b>Nº de processo:</b>
    <input type='text' name='procedit' class='procedit' style='border:0px solid #b3b3b3; width:100px; text-align:center; border-radius:5px; background-color:#bfbfbf;' maxlength'5' id='n_processo' value='".$row['n_processo']."' >
    </p>
```

E na hora de definir a mascara, usa o seletor ".procedit". Assim.

```
    $(".procedit").mask("99999",{placeholder:""})
```

Isso deve resolver parte do seu problema (ou todo);

Comment: user5978 funcionou pelas classes, obrigado. Agora no `AJAX` pus um `alert` de cada variável, mas funcionou apenas para a primeira linha. Sabe alguma forma de contornar o problema do mesmo?

Comment: Inclua na pergunta o código utilizado para fazer esta requisição AJAX.

Comment: `$("#btnedit").click(function(){
var proc=$("#procedit").val();
var nome=$("#nomeedit").val(); 
var cc=$("#ccedit").val();
var data_nasc=$("#data_nascedit").val();
alert("cheguei kirido");
alert(proc);
alert(nome);
alert(cc);
alert(data_nasc);
 $.post('actualiza.php',{ proc: proc, nome: nome, data_nasc: data_nasc, cc: cc },
  function(data)
  {
    $("body").html(data);
  })   

});`

Comment: var proc=$("#procedit").val(); ? Mesmo problema. Você esta usando id para buscar varios inputs, como eu disse, isso não rola. Troca para classe, e veja no que da.

Comment: Arranjei uma solução, porém aparecem alguma variáveis undefined, tenho de procurar melhor sobre isso. Mas eu fiz, nas classes: `class=nomeedit".$editar."` já que o `$editar` é o contador dos model, depois no botão, fiz `onclick='darupdate(".$editar.");'` e no `Javascript` `function darupdate(y)...`assim consegui concatenar as variaveis assim `var nome = $(".nomeedit"+y);` Também gostava de saber qual a diferença entre a classe e o ID, se puder explicar. :)

Comment: O problema do undefined, era porque esqueci-me de aplicar o contador num dos inputs. Agora o problema será a mascara, já que uso contador na classe dos inputs, também tenho de atribui-lo na máscara.

Comment: Edita a pergunta, e posta o código da requisição em ajax, indentado. Se possível.

Comment: já inclui o AJAX user5978

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38708/discussion-between-user5978-and-programmer2016).